# Codeigniter ActiveRecord, count records by category

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

Maybe I just can't think right currently. But what I want to try and figure out is how can I return a set of results that is the count of rows per category, in the DB. Without having to query based on each category.

The categories in this case are states. I have 90,000 rows of data with 50 different states dividing the data up. Is there a way of creating a count that is associated with each state?

I want to say `group_by` or something but I just honestly can't think of it right now. Ideas?

```
member | comment | state | dataset
----------------------------------
000    |something| CA    | an_object_of_data
000    |something| CA    | an_object_of_data
000    |something| CA    | an_object_of_data
000    |something| NY    | an_object_of_data
000    |something| NY    | an_object_of_data
000    |something| CA    | an_object_of_data
000    |something| CT    | an_object_of_data
000    |something| CA    | an_object_of_data
```

the above is an example of the db table in sorts. Imagine something like that with 90k rows and more `state`.

If I can some how get a count returned by grouping the results or something, ie: "CA=4", "CT=1", "NY=2"

Comment: yes you can. But it would be nice to know more about your db. show us a create table.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
select state,  count(state) from states group by state order by state ASC;
```

I guess this might work in its simplest way!

CI Style:

```
$this->db->select("state, count(state)");
$this->db->from("states");
$this->db->group_by("state");
$this->db->order_by("state", "ASC");
$this->db->get();
```

Comment: group_by? are you shure?

Comment: that actually works, exactly as I could have hoped! you have no idea how helpful that is, soo tired, crunching in last bits of stuff for a project. Just have to convert that to a CI active record variant of that query and Ill be good, I think I should be able to do that though using something like `$this->db->query("select count(state),state from states group by state order by state ASC");`

Comment: +1 and its good to see that there are also developers in Afghanistan :)

Answer (score 3):

The code is

```
$this->db->select('count(states.state) as count,state',false)
         ->from(states)
         ->group_by('states.state')
         ->get()
         ->result();
```

Comment: @BobbyDigital i am new to stack overflow,will follow the rules surely.